# Can I use duplicate each loop by Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a headache because of Thymeleaf.
I want to handle complex object in Thymeleaf like loop in loop.
See this code:

**thymeleaf code**

```
<tr th:each="wrapper:${logWrappers}">
    <td th:text="${wrapper.serverName}">
<tr th:each="log:${wrapper.logs}">
<tr th:text="${log.name}">
<tr th:each="debug:${log.debug}" th:text="${debug}"></tr>
</tr>
</tr>
</td>
</tr>
```

**model**

public class LogWrapper {
    private String serverName;
    private List logs;

```
// getters and setters
```

}

**object in model**

```
public class LogModule {
    private String name;
    private String logType;
    private List<String> debugs = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> infos = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

**send parameter**

```
model.addAttribute("logWrappers", logWrappers);
```

**problem**

```
<tr th:each="log:${wrapper.logs}">
```

This code is not working. How can i solve it?

**retry**

```
<tr> <td> <tr th:each="wrapper:${logWrappers}"> 
  <td th:text="${wrapper.serverName}"> 
   <tr th:each="log:${wrapper.logs}"> <td th:text="log.name"> 
    <tr th:each="debug:${log.debug}"> <td th:text="${debug}"></td> 
     </tr>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Error, nothing to display? Be more specific...

Comment: Also a `tr` and `tr` with text doesn't seem right, or this code isn't your actual code... But I doubt that `<tr th:text="${log.name}">` is what you wnat... Guess that should be a `<td>` instead...

Comment: thanks Deinum for your comment!
your are ritght .. "nothing to display" is coreect.

i will try you refer to your comment <td>

follow is my code

<tr>
<td>
<tr th:each="wrapper:${logWrappers}">
<td th:text="${wrapper.serverName}">
<tr th:each="log:${wrapper.logs}">
<td th:text="log.name">
<tr th:each="debug:${log.debug}">
<td th:text="${debug}"></td>
</tr>
</td>
</tr>
</td>
</tr>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: Don't add code as comments... Update your question instead, next to that, what you posted doesn't seem to match your comment...

Comment: i'm so sorry.. next time i will, 
stackoverflow is not yet familiar to me.

Comment: update my retry code in question.